# Vue trimming white spaces

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using vue.js on my app, and when displaying some content, vue is removing spaces when there's more than one space between words. Unfortunately I can't reproduce this on a fiddle (not sure why). I'm not familiar with vue (I'm more of a back-end), so I'm sorry for the lack of details. The HTML code to display is this: `<div slot="body" v-html="viewingEmail.message"></div>`. And a sample content would be any phrase that has two spaces, example: `Hello,  how are you?`. On that case, the app will display `Hello,how are you?`

Our vue dependencies are:

```
"vue": "^2.4.2",
"vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
"vue-flatpickr": "^2.3.0",
"vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.1.2",
"vue-loader": "^11.3.4",
"vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
"vue-select": "^2.2.0",
"vue-slider-component": "^2.3.6",
"vue-star-rating": "^1.4.0",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
"vue2-dropzone": "^2.2.7",
"vuedraggable": "^2.15.0",
"vuejs-paginate": "^1.1.0",
"vuex": "^2.2.1",
```

Comment: replace multiple spaces into one?

Comment: The app is displaying `Hello, how are you?` (one space after `,`) not `Hello,how are you?` (no space after `,`), right?

Comment: @acdcjunior the latter, with no spaces after.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `ref` and printing on the console, or adding a `white-space` style to see what happens?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vue is not trimming spaces. That's just how HTML works.

The space is there, see demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello,    Vue.js!'
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Notice how the spaces exist in HTML, even though they are not displayed.');
    console.log('divHTML', this.$refs.divHTML.outerHTML);
    console.log('divTEXT', this.$refs.divTEXT.outerHTML);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  v-html: <div v-html="message" ref="divHTML"></div>
  v-text: <div v-text="message" ref="divTEXT"></div>
</div>
```

You could just replace space chars with a `&nbsp;` HTML entity, but that would mess nested elements' attributes.

**My suggestion:** [use `white-space: pre-wrap;` style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

See demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello,    Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```css
.keep-spaces { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>With "white-space:pre-wrap;" spaces are preserved visually.</h3>
  v-html: <div v-html="message" class="keep-spaces"></div>
  v-text: <div v-text="message" class="keep-spaces"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was just about to write basically this myself, except  `white-space : pre-wrap;` might be more appropriate if it's really the space, not the wrapping, that you care about.

Comment: Yes, I agree. **`white-space : pre-wrap;`** may be a better option in the general case. @OP I suggest you try both and see what fits.